# R: Adding a scale to graph

Tags: r, plot, scale

I have created the graph I wanted in R, but it isn't scaled the way I expected it to. The graph I created is below. The x-axis is age and currently it's listed as "10,11,12,13...91 and above." I want it to be something more like "10,20,30...91 and above." so the x-axis is readable. How would I go about doing that in R? The code for the graph is also below.

[image]

```
 ggplot(data, aes(Age,Shoes))+
    geom_density(stat="identity")+
    facet_wrap(~Gender)
```

The data is my data set which includes the three columns Age, Shoes, and Gender. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks everyone!
Lizzie

Comment: `scale_x_continuous`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `scale_x_continuous()` in your case, as alistaire suggested. You will specify where you want breaks in the function. In the example below, I specified 5 and 10.

```
# Create a sample data
mydf <- data.frame(age = rep(c(1, 2, 4, 10, 6, 7, 5, 5, 8, 10), times = 10),
                  shoes = runif(n = 100, min = 20, max = 75))


### X is specified

ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x = age, y = shoes)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(5, 10))
```

[image]

```
### Default
ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x = age, y = shoes)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]